# Workflow SerializationException because of complex object

Tags: serialization, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, nonserializedattribute

I got the following exception:

> System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceException: Type ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb’ in Assembly ‘Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c’ is not marked as serializable. —> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb’ in Assembly ‘Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c’ is not marked as serializable

The error came from here:

```
public sealed partial class MyWorkflow : StateMachineWorkflowActivity
{
    public SPWorkflowActiviationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();
    private SPWeb spWebtemp;

    private SPWeb spWeb
    {
        get { return spWebtemp ?? (spWebtemp = workflowProperties.Web); }
    }

    ...
```

There are two blog posts I found:

- [... is not marked as serializable](http://pradeepkvd.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/microsoft-sharepoint-spuser-in-assembly-microsoft-sharepoint-version12-0-0-0-cultureneutral-publickeytoken71e9bce111e9429c-is-not-marked-as-serializable/)
- [Serialization Issue with Windows Workflow Foundation and Sharepoint Workflow](http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/12/01/serialization-issue-with-windows-workflow-foundation-and-sharepoint-workflow/)

There is one solution to be found to this problem: *Not have complex member objects as global variables*, but as a local variables - i.e. declare SPWeb locally (workflowProperties.Web) instead of on a global level.

So I would have to redeclare spWeb in every method I am using - which I deem rather ugly.

What I also tried is this:

```
...
[NonSerialized]
private SPWeb spWebtemp;

private SPWeb spWeb
{
    get { return spWebtemp ?? (spWebtemp = workflowProperties.Web); }
}
...
```

==> no more serialization exception!

**Are there any negative implications when using the `NonSerialized` attribute on this field?**
Or in other words - what are the implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply do :

```
private SPWeb spWeb
{
    get { return workflowProperties.Web; }
}
```

the lazy load of the spweb object is already handled by the properties property

Comment: that I didn't know - yet the question is about the implications of using NonSerialized not about lazy loading ;-)

Comment: I guess, you can use the NonSerialized safely. Just be careful when you want to access to this field, that the field is actually set

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it also would also work (the OnDeserialized Attribute):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx

[EDIT]

I haven't tested this, but I'm thinking something like this:

```
public sealed partial class MyWorkflow : StateMachineWorkflowActivity
{

public SPWorkflowActiviationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

[NonSerialized()]
private SPWeb spWebtemp;

private SPWeb spWeb
{
    get { return spWebtemp ?? (spWebtemp = workflowProperties.Web); }
}

[OnDeserialized()]
internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    spWebTemp = workflowProperties.Web;
}


...
```

Also, why not initialize the spWebtemp object in the constructor, or is that not possible with workflows?